# Enterprise Library SqlCacheDependency

Tags: c#, sql, caching, enterprise-library, sqlcachedependency

I am working with Enterprise Library Application Block in my application and need to use SqlCacheDependency, but Caching block does not have SqlDependency Expiration available, Tried to search, found a post with broken link (david hyden), there must be some way to use sql notification in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a cached version of the David Hayden link you are referencing:

http://web.archive.org/web/20100115060028/http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/04/30/2930.aspx

Here is an ICacheItemExpiration implementation from codeplex: https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/72118